# Is it possible to active extension according to custom product attribute is null or not in Magento

Tags: magento

I want to develop multiple extensions for Magento, two extension both replace product.info.media block, so I want to active one of them according to the custom attribute is null or not.

Currently, myModule.xml is like this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem" ifconfig="myModule/general/enabled">
            <type>skin_js</type><name>js/myModule/xxx.js</name>
        </action>
        <action method="addItem" ifconfig="myModule/general/enabled">
            <type>skin_js</type><name>js/myModule/xxx.js</name>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product.info.media">
        <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="myModule/general/enabled">
            <template>myModule/media.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Is it possible to add ifconfig condition to detect product custom attribute is null or not? Or other fallback mechanism to load other extension template for the same block.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would implement an empty container block via layout xml. Furthermore i would develop a custom block class were you can decide which template to load an add to the container.

Comment: Thanks. I just test it, I think my target can be achieved via your suggestion.